# How can I run an sql command on all databases at once?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, replace

I have circa 80 wordpress blogs, which write about my various sites. I want to update all posts in all databases for a specific string of text, in this instance, a domain name.

The script works perfectly fine, on one database, but I will need to make several changes, to ALL databases which will simply take far too long.

I need to be able to run these commands across every database at once, rather than one database at a time.

My script, as it works currently on a single database:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://mixudo.com');
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try executing this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE ', 
schema_name, '.\'wp_posts\' SET \'post_content\' = REPLACE(post_content, \'http://www.old-domain.com\', \'http://mixudo.com\');')
FROM information_schema.schemata
WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema','phpmyadmin', 'webauth');
```

and then reexecuting the result.

Source: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/20251

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a list of database names with usernames/passwords that you need the script to be executed on
2. For each database in this list do:
3. Log into that database and select it
4. Run the script on that database

That is the only way to do your task safely.

Comment: Thanks but this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid :)

I have backups in case it goes horribly wrong...

Comment: If you do decide to do that, remember PHP's set_time_limit(), especially if you have that many databases.

Comment: @user1883682 - You are going to have to bite the bullet. 1show databases` can give you a list to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of databases on a mysql server using the SHOW DATABASES command.  Using that as input you can write a shell script in whatever language you are capable that will foreach() through the list of databases, and running the UPDATE statement on each, by executing

```
use DBNAME;
```

Where DBNAME is the variable in the foreach.  The update statement should work the same on all the databases, as I assume each db has the same set of tables with the same tablenames in each.

To Ed Heal's point, this also assumes you're using the root/admin user for the server so that it will have rights to update all the tables.

Comment: Could you provide an example to run as an sql file, using my script example? Thx!

Comment: Probably not a good idea to blindly use `show databases`. I would just get the list and then manually check/edit to ensure that we are not adding system ones and others that should not be included.

Comment: Thanks, there are only wordpress databases on the system, its a dedicated server just for those sites.

I could do with a simple enough file that I can make changes to the strings, but will run on all databases so I'm not doing like 50 changes to 80 databases, one by one .. Thanks :)